# How to prove a recursive function not surjective

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Think of a function defined as follows:
$f(n + 1) = f(n)/2$ if $f(n)$ is even and $3f(n) + 1$ if $f(n$) is odd.

By writing out a few examples, it is not hard to $f(n)$ can not be $3f(0)+2$（and more...), but to prove it seems a bit tricky. I tried to prove it by using induction. Little has accomplished in that way.

Can anyone share some lights on this question?

Thank you!

Comment: What is $f(0)$ ? When do we stop the recursive function?

Comment: If $f(0)=0$ then it is surjective onto the singleton set $\{0\}$.

Comment: BTW, this is a famous function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Comment: The Collatz conjecture implies that the image of that function is a *finite* set for every choice of $f0)$.